Region based isolation problem related to Swift 6 migration
During migration to Swift 6 I ran into this issue, which I haven't found a way around as of yet.
The warning reads:

Passing closure as a 'sending' parameter risks causing data races between code in the current task and concurrent execution of the closure; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

The distilled sample code:
@Observable
class Helloworld {
    var hello: Bool = false
    func world() {
        Task { // Compiler warning: "Passing closure as a 'sending' parameter risks causing data races between code in the current task and concurrent execution of the closure; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode"
            await self.work()
        }
    }
    
    private func work() async {
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
            hello = true
        }
        catch {
            // Gotcha
        }
    }
}

How can we fix this?

You aren't compiling with Swift 6, aren't you? Otherwise, you would get an error.

Correct. After addressing this and a bunch of other issues I upgraded to swift 6.

The compiler error is not giving too much information here. With your code, imagine self.work being called parallels, there for, variable hello will have 2 write access from 2 different threads in a same time which cause data races as the error indicates. Using MainActor from your answer helps you eliminate possible of data races because now there only be one write/read access for Helloworld variables at one time thanks for Actor mechanism of protecting share mutable state.

I found out a way to fix this right away, and although I haven't gone through why this works, here is the final code:
@MainActor
@Observable
class Helloworld {
    var hello: Bool = false
    func world() {
        Task {
            await self.work()
        }
    }
    
    private func work() async {
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
            hello = true
        }
        catch {
            // Gotcha
        }
    }
}

Yes, I just added @MainActor on top of it all. I kind of was under the impression that this word would not be used with observables though.

You'll find the answer, why this works here and why the compiler issues an error in your original code here: https://www.swift.org/migration/documentation/swift-6-concurrency-migration-guide/dataracesafety/ .
Specifically, you'll need to understand how data, types and functions are associated to an isolation domain, that there is also a Non isolated domain (which is the default), that a task is also always associated to an isolation domain, and how a task obtains its isolation domain, either implicitly or explicitly via Isolation inference and Inheritance.

Thanks, I think that's it. I'm still reading up on these bits and this is truly helpful. I will say that I somehow had the impression that using Observable would automatically divert updates to MainActor, but seems like that was incorrect. Here is another good looking article on the subject.
